# HTML/CSS: getting <button>, enclosed in an <A>, to inherit style of surrounding <button>'s styled by css-grid

Tags: html, css, layout, css-grid

I am just becoming more acquainted with HTML/CSS. I have recently learned of the `css-grid` layout (intro [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)), and I had been using it to style my html buttons, as in the following image:

[image]

I have a few labels and text inputs, but most importantly, setting `display: grid` in the encompassing `div` allows the 3 button's on the right to be 1) lined up, and 2) possess that gray square style.

However, as soon as I envelop the third button in `<A>...</A>`, it loses the previous styling, and I get the following (out of line, and defaulting to the normal button style)

[image]

How could I force the button enclosed in `<A>` to display the same style as before?

I am including a [Codepen link](https://codepen.io/Shrushrwawenko/pen/joBbNE) that displays the same problem.

Comment: pls revise your question with a snippet that *replicates* your issue

Answer (score 1):

```html
<h1 class="Hello">Hello</h1>
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="1">Button 1</button>
  <button class="2">Button 2</button>
  <button class="3">Button 3</button>
  <a class="wrapper"><button class="4">Button 4</button></a>

</div>
```

I just tried adding the wrapper class to the  and it displayed correctly,

You can maybe try it to see if it works

Answer (score 1):

Having a button inside `<a>` tag is not valid HTML5.

> [HTML5 Spec Document](http://w3c.github.io/html/textlevel-semantics.html#the-a-element): 
>   The a element may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g., buttons or other links).

However adding

```
a button{
  height: 50px;
}
```

to your codepen fixed the problem.